# libvirt management is slow under ubuntu

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-14.04, libvirt, qemu

I've just done a fresh install of KVM/Qemu under Ubuntu 14.04.2 on an older (C2D gen) server with dual quad core xeons and 24 gb of ram. I'm finding that I'm waiting for operations in virsh for around 10-20 seconds. I can understand that some commands take time to complete, but feel that `virsh dumpxml test.domain` (glorified `cat test.domain.xml`) and `virsh list` shouldn't be taking this long to complete. Is this a well known bug? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot that I installed Kimchi on there to manage it. Killed the process and everything is much better. Derp....

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I forgot that I installed Kimchi on there to manage it. Killed the process and everything is much better. Derp...